# SCP remember password

Tags: ssh, passwords, rsync, scp

On debian, is there anyway for scp to remember the password I've typed in for the duration of my ssh logon, similar to how sudo does?

i.e. 
`PC ---ssh(putty)---> server 1 ---scp---> server 2`

I don't want to setup public/private keys because I don't have control of all the remote servers.  I just don't want to have to type my password in for every single file I'm copying.

Is this possible in anyway?!

Answer (score 2):

Only if you set up a key. You can then use `ssh-add` to add the private key to your local SSH agent which will then provide the key to the SSH client when asked. You will only need to enter the passphrase during the initial add.

Answer (score 2):

Use [sshpass](http://sshpass.sourceforge.net/):

> `ssh` uses direct TTY access to make sure that the password is indeed issued by an interactive keyboard user. `sshpass` runs `ssh` in a dedicated tty, fooling it into thinking it is getting the password from an interactive user.

```
sshpass -p 'password' scp -r user@example.com:/some/remote/path /some/local/path
```

You can also use `sshpass` with `ssh`, `rsync` and `scp`.